# Creating a custom PowerShell object from CSV input

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have the following CSV input:

```
id,name,surname,age,description
1,michael,jackson,50,desc1
2,james,hetfield,55,desc2
```

I want to convert it into the following format as a string:

```json
availableValues = [ 
    { 
        'value' : 'id=1,name=michael,surname=jackson,age=50', 
        'displayName' : 'michael', 
        'description' : 'desc1' 
    }, 
    {
        'value' : 'id=1,name=james,surname=hetfield,age=55', 
        'displayName' : 'james', 
        'description' : 'desc2' 
    } 
]
```

So I thought, I would build a custom PS object first and then format its output.

```bsh
$csvfile = "C:\Users\<blabla>\Desktop\scr\csv.txt"
$csv = Import-Csv $csvfile
$newobject = New-Object -TypeName PSOBject
Add-Member -NotePropertyName value -NotePropertyValue $csv -InputObject $newobject
Add-Member -NotePropertyName displayName -NotePropertyValue $csv.name -InputObject $newobject
Add-Member -NotePropertyName description -NotePropertyValue $csv.description -InputObject $newobject
```

So `$newobject` looks like this now:

```
PS> $newobject

value                                                                                                                                 displayName      description   
-----                                                                                                                                 -----------      -----------   
{@{id=1; name=michael; surname=jackson; age=50; description=desc1}, @{id=2; name=james; surname=hetfield; age=55; description=desc2}} {michael, james} {desc1, desc2}
```

The next step would be build an array of objects or maybe a hashtable but I could not figure it out how, I'm a bit lost. Could you point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

Use [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) to modify the objects `Import-Csv` produces:

```bsh
$availableValues = Import-Csv $csvfile | Select-Object @{n='value';e={
    'id={0},name={1},surname={2},age={3}' -f $_.id, $_.name, $_.surname, $_.age
}}, @{n='displayName';e={$_.name}}, description
```

Alternatively you could also create new custom objects:

```bsh
$availableValues = Import-Csv $csvfile | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'value'       = 'id={0},name={1},surname={2},age={3}' -f $_.id, $_.name, $_.surname, $_.age
        'displayName' = $_.name
        'description' = $_.description
    }
}
```